# R's capture.output() behaves differently when file=NULL vs. file=[file name]

Tags: r

When using `capture.output(..., file = NULL)` followed by a specification of what line you want captured, then only that line is captured:

```
capture.output(summary(lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)), file = NULL)[5]
[1] "Residuals:"
```

But when a file name is specified, it will capture the entire object:

```
capture.output(summary(lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)), file = "Results.txt")[5]
NULL
```

The content of `Results.txt`:

```
Call:
lm(formula = speed ~ dist, data = cars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.5293 -2.1550  0.3615  2.4377  6.4179 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  8.28391    0.87438   9.474 1.44e-12 ***
dist         0.16557    0.01749   9.464 1.49e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.156 on 48 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6511,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6438 
F-statistic: 89.57 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: 1.49e-12
```

How can I make R and/or `capture.output` only write the line I want to a file (in this toy example line no. 5)?

Comment: The `capture.output` function cannot "see" the `[5]` when there is a file destination. The only reason that it works with the NULL file is that the text stream is returned to the console as a `textConnection()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do so within `capture.output()`, but you can simply write the part of `capture.output()`'s output that you want to a file using, for example, `cat()`

```
cat(capture.output(summary(lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)))[5],file="Results.txt")
```

Comment: BondedDust beat me to it but I didn't have to edit, so who wins?  :)

Answer (score 2):

The side-effect of writing a file happens before the extraction "`[`" operation takes place when there is a file argument. So you need to write the value after it gets returned to the console/global environment:

```
  cat( capture.output( summary(lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)), file = NULL)[5] , 
         file="test.txt")
```

It would be pretty easy to wrap this into a function if you will be needing it repeatedly.